# Can I travel straight to Holland from the United Kingdom on my Etats Schengen multi visa

Tags: multiple-entry, schengen-visas

I am planning to travel to Holland on my multi entry 3 months visa that was issue by the French embassy in the United Kingdom. I have been to Paris 2 weeks ago for 2 days.

Comment: I don't believe the visa the OP has is a Type D. Aren't they issued for stays longer than 90 days (3 months)?

Comment: It's s type C visa for multi entries for the duration.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong duplicate in the comment, but the answer is yes. That is how a multiple-entry visa is supposed to work, to save both you and the consulates the paperwork.

- You must have days left on the duration. If no shorter duration is given, you can stay up to 90 days out of every 180 days. If a shorter total duration is given, this applies. Note that fractional days count full.
- You must plan to leave the Schengen area again.
- You must be able to afford your stay and bring enough money or means to pay. The amount per day is different for each Schengen country.

Comment: This was what I thought but just wanted to be on the safe side.